# Monads in C# -- why Bind implementations require passed function to return a monad?

Tags: c#, monads

Most examples of monads I saw in C# are written somewhat like that:

```
public static Identity<B> Bind<A, B>(this Identity<A> a, Func<A, Identity<B>> func) {
    return func(a.Value);
}
```

For example, see http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/01/monads-in-c-3-creating-our-first-monad.html.

The question is, what is the point of requiring `func` to return an `Identity<B>` ? If I use the following definition:

```
public interface IValue<A> {
    public IValue<B> Bind<B>(Func<A, B> func)
}
```

then I can actually use same `func` for for `Lazy<T>`, `Task<T>`, `Maybe<T>` etc without actually depending on actual type implementing `IValue`.

Is there something important I am missing here?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the example?

Comment: The first one? It is from  http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/01/monads-in-c-3-creating-our-first-monad.html. Added that link to the original question.

Comment: The `Bind` you define in `IValue<T>` is actually a `map` or `lift` function (in C# usually called `Select`)

Comment: So only thing `Bind` adds over `Lift` is a 'flattening' in the case where function does actually return a monad of the same type?

Comment: 'flattening' is one way to see it (in Scala bind is called `flatMap`), but think of a `Maybe<T>` monad: with `map` alone you can't go from "something with a value" to "no value" so you wouldn't be able to break the computation.

Comment: I see, yes. I think you should make your comment an answer since while Eric's response is great, I think it does not completely address my question of composing functions `T => Monad<U>` and `U => V`.

Comment: This raises another question -- what is the benefit of having separate `bind` and `lift` in C# where you can easily pass `Func<object>` that actually returns `Maybe` to `Maybe.lift` instead of `Maybe.bind`. Should `lift` in such a language just cast the result to see whether it should manage it specially? Well, you would not be able to create lists of lists if `Select` just flattened any lists it received from selector func, but it looks like an edge case. Ok, maybe it should be a separate question.

Comment: Indeed `lift` for a monad can be seen as a convenience function (i.e. non-essential) since it can be expressed in terms of `bind` and `return` (see http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#liftM ). A *very* convenient function.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer can you create an answer from your comment about lift? It is enough information for me to accept it for this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First off, consider the notion of *composition*. We can express composition as an operation on delegates easily:

```
public static Func<T, V> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, V> f, Func<T, U> g)
{
    return x => f(g(x));
}
```

So if I have a function g which is `(int x) => x.ToString()` and a function f which is `(string s) => s.Length` then I can make a composed function h which is `(int x) => x.ToString().Length` by calling `f.Compose(g)`.

That should be clear.

Now suppose I have a function g from `T` to `Monad<U>` and a function f from `U` to `Monad<V>`. I wish to write a method that composes these two functions that return monads into a function that takes a `T` and returns a `Monad<V>`. So I try to write that:

```
public static Func<T, Monad<V>> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, Monad<V>> f, Func<T, Monad<U>> g)
{
    return x => f(g(x));
}
```

Doesn't work. `g` returns a `Monad<U>` but `f` takes a `U`. I have a way to "wrap" a `U` into a `Monad<U>` but I don't have a way to "unwrap" one.

However, if I have a method

```
public static Monad<V> Bind<U, V>(this Monad<U> m, Func<U, Monad<V>> k)
{ whatever }
```

then I *can* write a method that composes two methods that both return monads:

```
public static Func<T, Monad<V>> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, Monad<V>> f, Func<T, Monad<U>> g)
{
    return x => Bind(g(x), f);
}
```

That's why Bind takes a func from `T` to `Monad<U>` -- because the whole point of the thing is to be able to take a function g from `T` to `Monad<U>` and a function f from `U` to `Monad<V>` and compose them into a function h from `T` to `Monad<V>`.

If you want to take a function g from `T` to `U` and a function f from `U` to `Monad<V>` then *you don't need Bind in the first place*. Just *compose the functions normally* to get a method from `T` to `Monad<V>`! The whole purpose of Bind is to solve this problem; if you wave that problem away then you don't need Bind in the first place.

UPDATE:

> In most cases I want to compose function g from `T` to `Monad<U>` and function f from `U` to `V`.

And I presume you then want to compose that into a function from `T` to `V`. But you can't guarantee that such an operation is defined! For example, take the "Maybe monad" as the monad, which is expressed in C# as `T?`. Suppose you have g as `(int x)=>(double?)null` and you have a function f that is `(double y)=>(decimal)y`. How are you supposed to compose f and g into a method that takes an int and returns the non-nullable `decimal` type? There is no "unwrapping" that unwraps the nullable double into a double value that f can take!

You can use Bind to compose f and g into a method that takes an int and returns a nullable decimal:

```
public static Func<T, Monad<V>> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, V> f, Func<T, Monad<U>> g)
{
    return x => Bind(g(x), x=>Unit(f(x)));
}
```

where Unit is a function that takes a `V` and returns a `Monad<V>`.

But there simply is no composition of f and g if g returns a monad and f doesn't return the monad -- there is no guarantee that there is a way to go back from the instance of the monad to an "unwrapped" type. Maybe in the case of some monads there always is -- like `Lazy<T>`. Or maybe there sometimes is, like with the "maybe" monad. There often is a way to do it, but there is not a *requirement* that you can do so.

Incidentally, notice how we just used "Bind" as a Swiss Army Knife to make a new kind of composition. Bind can make any operation! For example, suppose we have the Bind operation on the sequence monad, which we call "SelectMany" on the `IEnumerable<T>` type in C#:

```
static IEnumerable<V> SelectMany<U, V>(this IEnumerable<U> sequence, Func<U, IEnumerable<V>> f)
{
    foreach(U u in sequence)
        foreach(V v in f(u))
            yield return v;
}
```

You might also have an operator on sequences:

```
static IEnumerable<A> Where<A>(this IEnumerable<A> sequence, Func<A, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(A item in sequence)
        if (predicate(item)) 
            yield return item;
}
```

Do you really need to write that code inside `Where`? No! You can instead build it entirely out of "Bind/SelectMany":

```
static IEnumerable<A> Where<A>(this IEnumerable<A> sequence, Func<A, bool> predicate)
{
    return sequence.SelectMany((A a)=>predicate(a) ? new A[] { a } : new A[] { } );  
}
```

Efficient? No. But there is nothing that Bind/SelectMany cannot do. If you really wanted to you could build all of the LINQ sequence operators out of nothing but SelectMany.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, however I still have a question. In most cases I want to compose function g from `T` to `Monad<U>` and function f from `U` to `V`.  For example, I want to add `5` to `Lazy<int>`, so `5+()` is a function f from `int` to `int`, but I have a `Monad<int>`  (Lazy, from some previous function call). So the unwrapping case is still relevant, but why would I want `5+()` function to return a monad? Why can't I do both unwrapping and re-wrapping within a `Bind` function?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin The point is that the `Bind` operation is not designed to (only) solve the kind of problem you just described. To put it another way, `Bind` is overkill for that sort of problem.

Comment: @DanielPratt but what is designed for this problem? Functions in my case can not just be composed directly, because I need to understand how to apply a given operation to an internal value of the monad.

Comment: Someone already mentioned this in a comment to your question, but it appears you are looking for an operation that is generally called `map`. The .NET framework calls it `Select`. Take a look at the type of the `Enumerable.Select` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx It has pretty much the type you gave to `Bind` in your question.

Comment: I see, so the question should have been 'why monads use `bind` instead of `lift`', but that's probably to allow flattening.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin: I've updated my answer to respond to your second question.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks a lot, I still have some questions, but they are pretty far away from the original one, so I'll ask them separately.